# Does NYC ignore the files from .gitignore?

Tags: node.js

I have a `.gitignore` file who's ignoring a `coverage` folder, so I think that `nyc` is excluding this file as well but I don't find any documentation about that.

Do you know any reference for that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with NYC, so assuming that's [the `nyc` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc)… There's no mention of `gitignore` in [its documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc#excluding-files) or [source code](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc). Its docs state that you have to specify any ignore patterns in your project's `package.json`.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll need to add the ignore files to nyc to avoid future errors but I made some tests and it seems to be working with the `.gitignore` file only.

Answer (score -1):

gitignore - Specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore., refer [Git](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) Document

ex:

```
## generic files to ignore
*~
*.lock
*.DS_Store
*.swp
*.out

# rails specific
*.sqlite3
config/database.yml
log/*
tmp/*

# java specific
*.class

# python specific
*.pyc

# xcode/iphone specific
build/*
*.pbxuser
*.mode2v3
*.mode1v3
*.perspective
*.perspectivev3
*~.nib

# akka specific
logs/*

# sbt specific
target/
project/boot
lib_managed/*
project/build/target
project/build/lib_managed
project/build/src_managed
project/plugins/lib_managed
project/plugins/target
project/plugins/src_managed
project/plugins/project

core/lib_managed
core/target
pubsub/lib_managed
pubsub/target

# eclipse specific
.metadata
jrebel.lic
.settings
.classpath
.project

.ensime*
*.sublime-*
.cache

# intellij
*.eml
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.*.sw?
.idea

# paulp script
/.lib/

derby.log
metastore_db/
spark-dist-jar/target
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question. It isn't asking for a definition of `gitignore` files, but about whether the NYC tool references them.

Comment: As @JonathanLonowski said, my question is about the nyc, another example could be: does `.npmignore` use `.gitignore` to ignore files when I'm publishing a module? And the answer is yes. I know that because the documentation says it, but I couldn't find any docs for nyc.